# How to use System::String::Split with a split of three characters?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

namely, I want to split by a sequence of three white spaces, and then split again by a newline. I tried doing it, but it doesn't work:

```
array<wchar_t>^ separator = {'   '};
array<String^>^ QandA = x->Split(separator );
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.String.Split() contains an overload that takes an array of String as a delimiter.  So make a new array with the one element "   /n/r"  (or is it /r/n.. I can never remember), and use that as your delimiter.

Comment: +1  I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) is the overload suggested.

Answer (score 0):

[`Regex::Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) should work with complex delimiters, including multi-character sequences.

Comment: You've got a problem.. and then you think.. "Ah ha!  Regex!".  Now you have two problems.