# Use C++/CLI to Split System::String^ with multiple delimiters

Tags: c++-cli, string-parsing

I'm new to C++/CLI and am trying to split a `System::String^` with multiple delimiters.

```
System::String^ = 65 kb (65,546 bytes)
Split
System::String^ = 65546
```

I've found this code that would be great but it only works for `std::string` and I'm not allowed to convert `System::String^`.

```
std::string s = "65 kb (67,873 bytes)";
std::string delimiter = " (";

size_t pos = 0;
std::string token;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    std::cout << token << std::endl;
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
```

Any ideas on how I would do this?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742919/how-to-use-systemstringsplit-with-a-split-of-three-characters?rq=1) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a .NET class (System.String).  You need a .NET answer: [Does C# have a String Tokenizer like Java's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405/does-c-sharp-have-a-string-tokenizer-like-javas)